# How to solve dictionary changed size during iteration error?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want pop out all the large values and its keys in a dictionary, and keep the smallest. Here is the part of my program

```
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    for key1, value1 in dictionary.items(): 
            if key1!= key and value > value1:
                dictionary.pop(key)             
    print (dictionary)
```

Which results in

```
RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
```

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: You need to create another dictionary and move the elements to that dict.

Comment: I thought about to create a new empty dictinary and move the smallest item in it, but I still have the same problem

Comment: Can you use an another method than `pop` ?

Comment: I tried that way, but the program would have a key error.

Comment: Please update your question with an example of this dictionary, and a mockup of the desired results.

Comment: @YXH is the desired result a dict with only one key-value pair? Or are you just trying to find the smallest value?

Comment: @NadirSampaoli, this is my review practice. I just want to find out the smallest value without using min().

Comment: The modern solution is to use `for k in list(dict): del dict[k]`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Alternative solutions

If you're looking for the smallest value in the dictionary you can do this:

```
min(dictionary.values())
```

If you cannot use min, you can use sorted:

```
sorted(dictionary.values())[0]
```

### Why do I get this error?

On a side note, the reason you're experiencing an `Runtime Error` is that in the inner loop you modify the iterator your outer loop is based upon. When you `pop` an entry that is yet to be reached by the outer loop and the outer iterator reaches it, it tries to access a removed element, thus causing the error.
If you try to execute your code on Python 2.7 (instead of 3.x) you'll get, in fact, a `Key Error`.

### What can I do to avoid the error?

If you want to modify an *iterable* inside a loop based on its *iterator* you should use a [deep copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html#copy.deepcopy) of it.

Comment: the op question is: "How to solve dictionary changed size during iteration in Python"

Comment: Yes, OP asked "how do I avoid this error?" and this answer contains a couple of alternatives for actually doing what they were trying to do, an explanation of the reason why the error was happening and how to solve it if you really want to use a straight loop (see the very last sentence).

Comment: you are right, sorry. Please make small edit, so that I could vote back.

Comment: @minerals Ok, I've added some headings to hopefully make the answer more understandable

Comment: What if I want to iterate over `globals().items()`? I cant make deep copies of that. It raises a pickling error.

Comment: If you want to modify a dict, while iterating on it, you can do `for key in list(d): del d[key]` . You are now iterating on a list, not a reference to the dict itself. That's why you can't just iterate on `dict.keys()`, because it's a reference to the actual dict.

Comment: I think a shallow copy should suffice, shouldn’t it?

Answer (score 15):

In Python3, Try

```
for key in list(dict.keys()):
    if condition:
        matched
        del dict[key]
```

1 more thing should be careful when looping a dict to update its key:

Code1:

```
keyPrefix = ‘keyA’
for key, value in Dict.items():
    newkey = ‘/’.join([keyPrefix, key])
    Dict[newkey] = Dict.pop(key)
```

Code2:

```
keyPrefix = ‘keyA’
for key, value in Dict.keys():
    newkey = ‘/’.join([keyPrefix, key])
    Dict[newkey] = Dict.pop(key)
```

Result of code1/code2 is:

```
{‘keyA/keyA/keyB’ : ”, ‘keyA/keyA/keyA’: ”}
```

My way to resolve this unexpected result:

```
    Dict = {‘/’.join([keyPrefix, key]): value for key, value in Dict.items()}
```

Link: https://blog.gainskills.top/2016/07/21/loop-a-dict-to-update-key/

Answer (score 7):

You can use [copy.deepcopy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) to make a copy of the original dict, loop over the copy while change the original one.

```
from copy import deepcopy

d=dict()
for i in range(5):
    d[i]=str(i)

k=deepcopy(d)

d[2]="22"
print(k[2])
#The result will be 2.
```

Your problem is iterate over something that you are changing.

Comment: `d.copy() ` will do the same

Answer (score 2):

Record the key during the loop and then do dictionary.pop(key) when loop is done. Like this:

```
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    for key1, value1 in dictionary.items(): 
            if key1!= key and value > value1:
                storedvalue = key
    dictionary.pop(key)
```

Comment: but it still change the size.

Comment: Then store keys in list. And remove all dictionary items after both loops are done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to solve it:

1. From the dictionary, get a list of keys, sorted by value
2. Since the first key in this list has the smallest value, you can do what you want with it.

Here is a sample:

```
# A list of grades, not in any order
grades = dict(John=95,Amanda=89,Jake=91,Betty=97)

# students is a list of students, sorted from lowest to highest grade
students = sorted(grades, key=lambda k: grades[k])

print 'Grades from lowest to highest:'
for student in students:
    print '{0} {1}'.format(grades[student], student)

lowest_student = students[0]
highest_student = students[-1]
print 'Lowest grade of {0} belongs to {1}'.format(grades[lowest_student], lowest_student)
print 'Highest grade of {0} belongs to {1}'.format(grades[highest_student], highest_student)
```

The secret sauce here is in the sorted() function: instead of sorting by keys, we sorted by values.

Answer (score 0):

As I read your loop right now, you're looking to keep only the single smallest element, but without using `min`. So do the opposite of what your code does now, check if  `value1 < minValueSoFar`, if so, keep key1 as minKeySoFar. Then at the end of the loop (as Zayatzz suggested), do a `dictionary.pop(minKeySoFar)`

As an aside, I note that the `key1!=key` test is irrelevant and computationally inefficient assuming a reasonably long list.

```
minValueSoFar = 9999999;   # or whatever
for key,value in dictionary.items():
    if value < minValueSoFar:
        minValueSoFar = value
        minKeySoFar = key
dictionary.pop(minKeySoFar)   # or whatever else you want to do with the result
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to just keep the key with the smallest value, I would do it by first finding that item and then creating a new dictionary containing only it. If your dictionary was `d`, something like this would do that in one line:

```
d = dict((min(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]),))
```

This will not only avoid any issues about updating the dictionary while iterating it, it is probably faster than removing all the other elements.

If you must do the modifications in-place for some reason, the following would work because it makes a copy of all the keys before modifying the dictionary:

```
key_to_keep = min(d.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])[0]

for key in list(d):
    if key != key_to_keep:
        d.pop(key)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to dictionary changed size during iteration:

```py
for key,value in list(dictionary.items()):
    for key1, value1 in list(dictionary.items()): 
            if key1!= key and value > value1:
                dictionary.pop(key)             
print (dictionary)
```

> Better use it with **caution!** when using this type of code, because `list(dictionary.items())` calculated when the complier enters first time to loop. Therefore any change made on dictionary won't affect process inside the current loop.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a list with the vaules you want to delete and than run a second for loop:

```
for entry in (listofkeystopop):
        dictionary.pop(entry)
```