# del tuple-keys from nested dict; avoid runtime and type error

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested, typeerror

I have generated a large, nested dictionary from a pandas dataframe that was originally from an .xlsx sheet. Through the process, some of the empty cells from my excel sheet were imported as 'nan' and the values are stored in tuples, which serve as keys. The resulting dictionary looks something like this:

```
d_nans = {'feature1': {('1', '2'): [{'item1':'value1', 'item2': 'value2'}], 
                        ('nan', 'nan'): [{'item3':'value3', 'item4': 'value4'}]},
          'feature2': {('3', '10'): [{'item5':'value5', 'item6': 'value6'}], 
                       ('nan', 'nan'): [{'item7':'value7', 'item8': 'value8'}], 
                       ('23', '40'): [{'item9':'value9', 'item10': 'value10'}]},
          'feature3': {('21', '5000'): [{'item51':'value51', 'item61': 'value61'}], 
                       ('nan', 'nan'): [{'item71':'value71', 'item81': 'value81'}], 
                       ('560', '2400'): [{'item19':'value19', 'item110': 'value110'}]}}
```

I need a way to edit the dict to remove all key:value pairs where the keys have the value ('nan', 'nan'). I tried this:

```
for key, value in d_nans.items():
    seq_id = key
    feature_type = value
    for key, value in feature_type.items():
        if type(key) == tuple:
            if key[0] == 'nan':
                del feature_type[key]
```

Runtime Error: 'dictionary changed size over iteration'

which I tried to solve using some code from [How to solve dictionary changed size during iteration in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13519644/how-to-solve-dictionary-changed-size-during-iteration-in-python/13519858)

```
for key, value in d_nans.items():
    seq_id = key
    feature_type = value
    for key, value in feature_type.items():
        for sub_key in list(feature_type.keys()):
            if sub_key[0] == 'nan':
                del dict[sub_key]
```

but this gives me

```
TypeError: 'type' object does not support item deletion
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`dict.pop`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.pop) to remove specific keys if they exist. Specify a default value to avoid `KeyError` if the key does not exist. Since you have a nested dictionary, you can use a `for` loop.

```
for v in d_nans.values():
    v.pop(('nan', 'nan'), None)
```

It's not normally a good idea to modify a dictionary as you iterate over it, but you get away with it here because you aren't deleting / adding keys in the parent `d_nans` dictionary.

Now let's look at your two attempts:

1. Your first attempt fails because your dictionary size changes as you iterate. This is explained explicitly in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects):

> Iterating views while adding or deleting entries in the dictionary may
>   raise a `RuntimeError` or fail to iterate over all entries.

2. `dict` is a class, not an instance. Therefore, you cannot use `del dict[key]`. Irrespective, as per your first attempt, this isn't a good idea and will nonetheless fail.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through the inner dictionaries (`feature_type`) to see if `('nan', 'nan')` exists, you can just check if `feature_type` contains `('nan', 'nan')'`. This way, you can avoid both errors. Try this code:

```
for _, feature_type in d_nans.items():
    if ('nan', 'nan') in feature_type:
        del feature_type[('nan', 'nan')]
```

If you input your example into this loop, `d_nans` will become the following:

```
{'feature1': {('1', '2'): [{'item1': 'value1', 'item2': 'value2'}]},
'feature2': {('3', '10'): [{'item5': 'value5', 'item6': 'value6'}], ('23', '40'): [{'item9': 'value9', 'item10': 'value10'}]},
'feature3': {('21', '5000'): [{'item51': 'value51', 'item61': 'value61'}], ('560', '2400'): [{'item19': 'value19', 'item110': 'value110'}]}}
```